# Getting the last updated/commited file in git repository of VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to deltafy the deployment of pipelines of Azure Data Factory. In other words, I am planning to deploy only the recently modified pipelines or recently added pipelines to the ADF in Azure portal. Currently, I use powershell task in my CD pipeline to deploy all the pipelines. How do I get the recently modified pipelines using the timestamp? Any suggestions will help. :)

Comment: Do you mean you want to CI and CD for the changed file(s) for the latest commit of your git repo? But build and deploy will for all the files of your latest commit.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT HI Marina. Build all the files but push/publish only the modified files based on the timestamp...is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to build for all files and deploy for the changed file(s). I give the way in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build all the files but push/publish only the modified files to deploy, that’s possible.

You can use a PowerShell task to get the last commit id (sha-1 value) in `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`, and then use `git show <commit id>` to find which files are changed in the commit, then copy these files to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`. And finally publish these files to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can get changed files by using the REST API.

Simple powershell script:

```
Param(
 [string]$collection,
 [string]$project,
 [string]$repository,
 [string]$commit,
  [string]$token
)
$u="$($collection)$($project)/_apis/git/repositories/$repository/commits/$commit/changes"
Write-Output $u
$changedFiles=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$token)))
$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $u -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -ContentType "application/json"

Foreach($c in $result.changes)
{
    If($c.item.isFolder -ne 'true')
    {
        Write-Output $c.item.path
        $changedFiles.Add(($c.item.path))
    }
}
```

Arguments (check Allow scripts to access OAuth token option in build/release definition):

```
-collection $(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri) -project $(System.TeamProject) -repository $(Build.Repository.Name) -commit $(Build.SourceVersion) -token $(System.AccessToken)
```